# Searching within a Request Payload in XHR request at Network tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Using the `Search` pane in Chrome DevTools seems to yield results only within the response's scope (Response Headers and the Response itself) for each and every recorded resource.

But when it comes to searching for a specific string/regex within the Request scope, either the Request Headers or the Request Body itself, the `Search` pane doesn't yield and results and outputs "No matches found.".

[image: Search pane doesn't search within Request scope]

The official Chrome Developer documentation doesn't explicitly state the `Search` pane searches within the request stating:

> [*Use the Search pane when you need to search the HTTP headers and
> **responses** of all resources for a certain string or regular expression.*](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#search)

Am I missing something that is already natively integrated within the DevTools or should I just come up with a workaround like exporting the recorded resources as a HAR file, and then look it up using a Text Editor, or alternatively, as I'm looking for a way to do so on the fly, overriding the `XmlHttpRequest` object, logging all the request to the console and search it in there?

Just looking for a quick and easy way to find those resources by string/regex within the DevTools itself...